# Have been/ was... difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning, present-perfect, progressive-aspect

**I've been** studying all morning.

**I've been** studying all morning **long**.

I **was** studying all morning.

How are the first, and the third different in meaning?
What's the difference between the first, and the second?

Comment: Note that although *all day long* (and to a lesser extent, *all week/month/year long*) are idiomatically well-established, it's a relatively unusual usage for shorter periods like *all morning/afternoon long*.

Answer (score 1):

For the first two, no difference.
***long*** just emphasises.

The tenses are used for different purposes.
The **present perfect continuous** shows an action that **began** in the past and is still in **progress**. (The action is not yet finished.)

> **I've been studying** all morning.
>   (I started to study at some point in the morning and I'm still studying. The morning isn't finished.)

The **past continuous** describes a scene in the past, or a temporary action that was in progress in the past interrupted by another action. For instance,

> I **was studying** all morning till you **arrived**.

Comment: "All day " is not the same as "when he came"or "at 7 o'clock",Isn't it? And with Present Perfect Continuous does it mean it's still morning?

Comment: @V.V. I slipped the *all morning* in my past continuous example. I've just edited and given more details on those.